# QColor Hot to get darker image (array of pixels) in qt creator (using function darker)?

Tags: qt, pixel, hsl, qcolor

Hi i have a simple question:
I need to make darker a image (array of them), by converting rgb to hsl and back.
This is my code (just reading pixel by pixel and send it to console):

```
for (int y=0 ; y<32 ; y++) {
  for (int x=0 ; x<32 ; x++) {
      QColor color=QColor::darker(300); // there is wrong :( little help pls
      QColor color(image.pixel(x, y));
      uint red = color.red(); uint green = color.green(); uint blue = color.blue();
      qDebug() << red << green << blue;
    }
}
```

Function description is [Here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcolor.html#darker)

Info:
QColor ilb for Qt Creator for editing images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`darker()` is a member function, you need to invoke it from a color instance:

```
QColor color = someColor.darker(300);
```

You also declare a `QColor color` twice.

Comment: Thanks, thats right, i was changed and it works perfect :), my changed line: QColor color_temp(image.pixel(x, y)); QColor color = color_temp.darker(300);